# kaggle dataset or python split CLI

Tags: python, opencv, kaggle

I downloaded the dataset from kaggle:
https://www.kaggle.com/c/dogs-vs-cats/data

Then tried to get image label from the downloaded data using cv2.split('.')[-3] command.  (code in the end)

However, i got an "index out of range error".  I checked the filename and see the filename after unzip from kaggle datasets is only 1.jpg, 2.jpg, 3.jpg.

From what I read, the dataset should have label in the filename. i.e.
https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788475655/23/ch23lvl1sec118/deep-learning-for-cats-versus-dogs

So my question is

Q1: I assume my python syntax is right.  As it looks like I would only have two argument [0] and [1] with filename of "num.jpg" not "label.num.jpg", right?

Q2: if so, anyone can help me to point out why I cannot get the right datasets with label in the filename?

ps: I am really new in python, kaggle, (or programming area).

Thank you
Mira

ps: my partial code:

```
for img in tqdm(os.listdir(TRAIN_DIR))
    path = os.path.join(TRAIN_DIR, img)
    img_data = cv2.imread(path)
    cv2.imshow('train_data_image:', img_data)
    print ('test:', img.split('.')[-3])
```

Answer (score 1):

just FYI - I found the answer for my question...

It turns out I was using the test data which indeed should not contain the label in the dataset.  I download the train data and it does have the label (dog/cat) in the filename.

thanks!
Mira